# If $A$ is an algebra, $Sym^n(A)$ is an algebra. Where can I learn more about this algebra structure?

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, plethysm

$\newcommand{\Vect}{\mathsf{Vect}}
\newcommand{\nats}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}}
\newcommand{\Alg}{\mathsf{Alg}}
\newcommand{\CAlg}{\mathsf{CAlg}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}$
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0, let $\Vect$ be the category of vector spaces over $k$, and let $n \in \nats$ (one can get away with a commutative ring $k$ where $n!$ is invertible). Let $\Alg$ be the category of $k$-algebras, and $\CAlg$ the category of commutative $k$-algebras.

Consider the $n$-fold symmetric power $\Sym^n$, a nonlinear functor. This functor has a lax symmetric monoidal structure given by the map $\Sym^n V \otimes \Sym^n W \to \Sym^n(V \otimes W)$, $v_1 \cdot \dots \cdot v_n \otimes w_1 \cdot \dots \cdot w_n \mapsto \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (v_1 \otimes w_{\sigma 1}) \cdot \dots \cdot (v_n \otimes w_{\sigma n})$ (there is something to check here -- a similar formula, with some signs thrown in, makes sense in the case of the $n$th alternating power $\wedge^n$, but in that case the requisite diagrams do not commute). As a consequence, we get functors $\Sym^n: \Alg \to \Alg$ and $\Sym^n: \CAlg \to \CAlg$. These constructions are not familiar (to me). For one thing, these algebra structures don't seem to have anything to do with the algebra structure on $\Sym(A) = \oplus_n \Sym^n(A)$ (which ignores the multiplication on $A$).

**Question:** If $A$ is an algebra, what is this algebra structure on $\Sym^n(A)$ called, and where can I find out more about it?

**An analogous, simpler construction:** The lax symmetric monoidal structure on $\Sym^n$ descends from a lax symmetric monoidal structure on the $n$th tensor power functor $T^n: \Vect \to \Vect$, $V \mapsto V^{\otimes n}$, where the lax monoidal structure is $T^n V \otimes T^n W \to T^n(V \otimes W)$, $v_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v_n \otimes w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes w_n \mapsto v_1 \otimes w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v_n \otimes w_n$. So if $A$ is a $k$-algebra, $T^n A$ is a $k$-algebra, with "component-wise" multiplication $(a_1 \otimes a_2)(a_3 \otimes a_4) = a_1 a_3 \otimes a_2 a_4$, and so we have a functor $T^n : \Alg \to \Alg$ which restricts to $T^n: \CAlg \to \CAlg$. This functor is not very mysterious: $\Hom_\Alg(T^n A, B)$ is just $n$ commutating algebra homomorphisms $A \to B$, and in particular, $T^n$ is just the $n$-fold coproduct on commutative algebras.

**The case $n=2$:** Let's look at $\Sym^2(A)$, and assume for simplicity that $A$ is commutative. This algebra has multiplication $(a_1 \cdot a_2)(a_3 \cdot a_4) = \frac{1}{2} \left( a_1 a_3 \cdot a_2 a_4 + a_1 a_4 \cdot a_2 a_3\right)$ (I'm using "$\cdot$" to denote the symmetric tensor and juxtaposition to denote multiplication in $A$ or in $\Sym^2(A)$). This algebra is generated additively by the square elements by the usual polarization identity $a_1 \cdot a_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( (a_1 + a_2)\cdot (a_1 + a_2) - a_1 \cdot a_1 - a_2\cdot a_2 \right)$. So we get a natural embedding $\Hom_\Alg(\Sym^2(A),B) \hookrightarrow \Hom_{\mathrm{Monoid}}(A, B)$ (where $A$ and $B$ are considered as multiplicative monoids) via $\phi \mapsto f$, where $f(a) := \phi(a \cdot a)$. We can characterize the image of this embedding and thus the functor corepresented by $\Sym^2(A)$: I believe that algebra homomorphisms $\phi: \Sym^2(A) \to B$ correspond to monoid homomorphisms $f: A \to B$ such that

1. $f(\lambda a) = \lambda^2 f(a)$ for all $\lambda \in k$
2. $f(a_1 + a_2 + a_3) - f(a_1 + a_2) - f(a_2 + a_3) - f(a_1 + a_3) + f(a_1) + f(a_2) + f(a_3) = 0$.
3. $f(a_1^2 + a_2^2) = (f(a_1) - f(a_2))^2 + (f(a_1 + a_2) - f(a_1) - f(a_2))^2$

(1) corresponds to $\phi$ respecting scalar multiplication, (2) corresponds to $\phi$ respecting addition, and (3) is a special case of $\phi$ respecting multiplication which I believe generates all cases thereof.

**Question:** Is a multiplicative monoid homomorphism satisfying (1),(2), and (3) something that has a name?

(2), in particular, looks very suggestive -- it seems like a sort of inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: It sounds like you have in mind symmetric tensors when you say the symmetric power. In that case, isn't your construction just $(A^{\otimes n})^{S_n}$, at least if $A$ is commutative? This is functions on $\left( \text{Spec } A \right)^n / S_n$.

Comment: There's something to check here -- but yes, apparently that's all it is. Thanks, I surely should have tried thinking about this geometrically.

Comment: As far as your particular example, I believe that 1) and 2) together describe the most general thing that could reasonably be called a quadratic function (between, say, two abelian groups, or more generally between two modules over the same commutative ring $k$).

Comment: Keywords: universal multiplicative polynomial law, symmetric tensors. Names: Norbert Roby, Dan Laksov, Anders Thorup (the latter two have a joint paper on this; the first has at least two, both in french). Daniel Harrer ' s thesis, soon to appear, also uses them at some point. Sorry for the telegraphic response (no time right now).

Comment: Actually, Section 1 of arXiv:0803.0618 by David Rydh gives an overview. Follow references from there.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks, this is just what I hoped for! Google scholar doesn't link to Roby's papers: his [thesis](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/browse?id=ASENS_1963_3_80_3) on the divided power algebra and polynomial morphisms, and a [later paper](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5496915v/f25.item.r=comptes%20rendus%20des%20s%C3%A9ances%20de%20l'acad%C3%A9mie%20des%20sciences%20s%C3%A9rie%20A%201980%20tome%20290%20n19) on the multiplicative structure on the $n$th grading of the divided power algebra. In the case where $n!$ is invertible this should all reduce to what I have above.

Comment: I would appreciate to read a canonical answer to this question. I've skimmed through the linked references and didn't found anything about this algebra $\mathrm{Sym}^n(A)$. Specifically, I wonder what the functor corepresented by $\mathrm{Sym}^n(A)$ looks like for $n>2$.

Comment: @HeinrichD I'd like this too. In particular, I'd like to know how Roby's ideas fit in with other notions of "polynomial" in the literature. Here's an updated link to [Roby's Thesis](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1124).